# delete string combobox item C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Thanks for your help. All of you (Literally)

I checked another part of my code where I was updating an entry and I used that code and modified it. Now it works

**Here it is**

```
string sql = "DELETE from Login WHERE UserName = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;


            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            int rowdel = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

This is my code for deleting the particular row from a database that is selected through a combo box. My teacher used this same code and his programme worked. However it is showing an error on :

**" int rowInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); "**

it says

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '='.**

here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server = HP-PC\\SQLExpress; Database = CProject; Trusted_Connection = True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = " + comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            int rowInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            label7.Text = rowInserted.ToString();

            conn.Close();


        }

        private void AddDeleteUsers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionstring = "Server=HP-PC\\SQLExpress;Database=CProject;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select UserName from Login";

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["UserName"].ToString());
            reader.Close();

            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You are also open to SQL injection attacks, so expect a wave of people telling you that. You also have the SQL (in a variable called `sql`), that is being run, take it, run it on the database *yourself*, does it work? The value of `comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString()` is what?

Comment: What was the value of the name you submitted?

Comment: When comparing a string, it needs to be surrounded with quotes. Alternatively look at providing parameters to your SQL command instead

Comment: @Arran it's the username that is being list down in a combo box

Comment: @MomalRazak, ok, great, so now, like I said, get the value of the `sql` variable, look at what it's generating.

Comment: @Arran it shows the proper names from the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give you a hint.

The error message is in your SQL code, in this line:

```
    string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = " + comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString();
```

The problem is that SQL needs text in single quotes, such as  `'text'` ...

Without providing the answer (since this is homework) I think this give you enough to figure it out?

**Edit "by popular demand"**

By the way, one of the reasons that it is not recommended to just take a value from the HTML input (your ComboBox) is that it could be manipulated by a malicious person and replaced with SQL code, which is known as SQL Injection.

To avoid that, the use of Parameters is recommended.

An example would be

```
    string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = @UserName"
```

Then you would have to add a parameter to your command before you execute it

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString());
```

This prevents someone from mutating your SQL statement into something sinister.

Comment: @MarkKram do you think that the OP is at that point in his studies? Everything at the right time... he's not writing a critical business app but just trying to learn the ropes.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin that is not for us to decide

Comment: You mean I should do this string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = '" + comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString() + "'";

Comment: @MomalRazak almost --- you only need one single quote and one double quote on each side...

Comment: @DavidKhaykin so we should allow him to develop bad programming skills then??

Comment: @MarkKram im a she. And i'm just a beginner dude. Calm down

Comment: @MarkKram - not at all. I am just advocating "walk before you run" - it is important to know all the ways of doing a task, and why some are better or worse than others, not just learn "what everyone says is the right way". Someone else can say, this should be LinqToEntities and not be wrong.

Comment: @MomalRazak "Dude" would you rather learn the correct way or the wrong way? If it is the later then by all means follow David's solution.

Comment: @MarkKram btw I updated my answer with the parameterized version and an explanation of the benefit.

Comment: @CR41G14 - I didn't decide that, I inferred it based on the question itself.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin while I understand what you were attempting to accomplish, I have to say that you are doing him any good. Most if not all of my "Bad Programming" Practices were learned during the first few months I was learning to program. Old habits die hard.

Comment: @MarkKram let's just agree to disagree. :) By the way she already mentioned she is a she :) (And to OP sorry for also assuming that, by the way in my earlier comment)

Comment: @DavidKhaykin i have done the single quote thing before posting here. It's not working. I guess i'll just have to ask my teacher

Comment: @DavidKhaykin I'll agree with you on your second to last comment ;-)

Comment: @DavidKhaykin **I did this. Its working now **

string sql = "DELETE from Login WHERE UserName = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;


            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            int rowdel = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");

Comment: Nice!!!! Glad it helped and now you know both ways, so @MarkKram should be happy! :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = " + comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString();
```

to this

```
string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = '" + comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString() + "'";
```

You need single quotes around around the text.

Comment: I had tried this before and I tried it again. It gives no error but it does not delete the row.

Comment: Well, what is the value of `comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString()`? Does it exist in your database?

Comment: of course it does. the combo box lists them down too (the proper entries)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = '" + comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString() + "'";
```

It is better to use `SqlParameter` to avoid sql injection.

```
        string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = @username";

        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString());

        int rowInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = '" + comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString()+ "'";
```

is better, no?

Be carefull with Sql injection by the way...

Comment: Thanks for the -1 guys, I definitely think that it is fair!

Comment: Thomas I didn't actually down vote you I simply stated it in my comment. I typically down down vote posts unless there is something really wrong. I just upvoted your post.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent SQL Injection Attacks you should use a parameterized Query:

```
    string connectionString = "Server = HP-PC\\SQLExpress; Database = CProject; Trusted_Connection = True";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "delete from [Login] where UserName = @UserName;";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("UserName", comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```